# DynamoDB.putItem function not saving item with sls command

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I am having trouble with my Lambda function with Serverless framework, which should be putting data to DynamoDB. I'm unsure of the issue as I am getting no error message in the console when I run: `sls invoke local -f scrape -d 'the-last-bookstore-los-angeles`.

**saveRatingsToDB.js**

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports = (data, businessName) => {
  console.log('data saving...');
  console.log(data);
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Item: {
      id: uuid.v1(),
      businessName: businessName,
      reviewCount: data.reviewCount,
      rating: data.rating,
      createdAt: JSON.stringify(new Date())
    }
  };

  // I am can log params okay, but nothing with dynamoDb.put is logged to the console

  dynamoDb.put(params, error => {
    console.log('putting data');
    if (error) {
      console.log(`Error saving data to DynamoDB: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
      return Promise.reject(
        `Error saving data to DynamoDB: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`
      );
    } else {
      console.log('data saved');
      return Promise.resolve(params.Item);
    }
  });
};
```

**handler.js**

```
'use strict';
const { getPage, parsePage, saveRatingsToDB } = require('./utils');

module.exports.scrape = async (event, context) => {
  console.log('Function triggered', event);
  const name = event;
  const page = await getPage(name);
  const data = await parsePage(page);
  const db = await saveRatingsToDB(data, name);

  return db;
};
```

**serverless.yaml**

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-2
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: my-table-name
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn_reference_"
package:
  include:
    - utils/**
```

As mentioned, I get no error message in the console. I can the log and see the `params` object from the `saveRatingsToDB.js`, but nothing within the actual `dynamoDb.put` function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried to run `saveRatingsToDB` as an asynchronous function by doing:

```
const db = await saveRatingsToDB(data, name);
```

Unfortunately, with the way this function is written currently, it's not an asynchronous function. The reason while you don't see the log inside `dynamoDb.put` is because the `saveRatingsToDB` function doesn't wait for the asynchronous callback to finish but return earlier.

To make `saveRatingsToDB` properly an asynchronous function and force it to wait for the callback, you can return a dynamoDb.put as a promise from that function:

```
module.exports = (data, businessName) => {
  ...

  // use dynamoDb.put().promise() to return a promise from dynamoDb transaction
  return dynamoDb.put(params, error => {
    ...
    // Do whatever with the error
  }).promise();
};
```